# Stacking UV's for more detail from bake?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking

I'm texturing a house to use as a prop in my game project and I'm quite happy with how the original model looks in Blender. The baked version however looks quite undetailed, first I tried to increase the texture size from 1024 to 2048 and then to 4096 and it does indeed get better but 4096 texture seems quite a lot higher than people usually use. So I did some digging and if I'm reading it correctly it would be a good idea to stack my seamless UV's (mainly the walls and windows I guess) on top of each other so I can make them all a lot bigger in comparison. I'm not quite sure of the workflow however. Even more because I'm guessing the origianl UV's and the bake UV's must be stacked exactly the same way (rotation of the stack shouldn't affect this though?) or the baking will make artifacts when it bakes the UV's on top of each other? Can someone please explain me how this is done or link to a tutorial that explains it? This must be quite a standard skill to know, right?

EDIT:
So here's some pretty paint pictures to demonstrate what I'm trying to do but don't know how and if its the right way.

First my main models UV that are separate and which I'd like to stack on each other:
[image]

Secondly the UV (didn't draw the other objects UVs for simplicity) of the whole model I'd like to bake it into. Because there's more UV's (doors, roof, windows etc.) to unwrap this materials UV's are usually all over the place. I'd imagine that you have to stack that materials UV's identically to the original map and then I'd scale it up to as the stacking gives me more room for all the UV's.
[image]

And thirdly a picture of what how the model looks like right now. It might help to figure out what I'm talking about:
[image]

brockmann was talking about using multiple objects to accomplish this as well, but I haven't found a good resource yet to tell me about drawbacks (if there are any) of using multiple objects to build one object in a game engine (Unity in this case).

Comment: You can offset the UV's x units if they are identical. However, there is only one UV slot in Game Engines so what you can do is splitting up the object onto multiple ones, highly depends on the goal and the model though. Suggest add more detail to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is it better etiquette to edit my original question with the added information or to post it as a comment to yours?

Comment: No problem, just edit your question if you can provide further details: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Alright! Added some details that hopefully help. And I'll check the help section next time!

Comment: If you're baking, either bake just one object or don't reuse UV space. It's contradictory to bake multiple objects expecting different results for each, but still expect to use a shared UV space for them - you can't have your cake and eat it too!

Comment: Okay. So how should I tackle this? If I just bake everything on a 1024 texture it looks like a something straight from golden eye. The model doesn't need to be fantastic looking but it'd be nice if it was a bit closer to the original model. The 4096 texture is a bit closer but I just have this gut feeling that there's a trick or two I can use to make the texturing more high definition without just pumping up the texture size.

Comment: If you have bricks made out of geometry and want to bake it, you can make a bigger wall of bricks, bake that to a texture, and then use that texture. If you have a continuous texture, you can offset those textures a little bit (or flip horizontally, vertically etc.) as brockmann suggested. But if you bake your textures directly to objects, you have only the information in exact spots, you can't (shouldn't) offset. Offsetting a baked texture also defeats the purpose of baking, which is supposed to generate a texture specifically mimicking a high poly object.